# Alternative of UNION and DISTINCT in spark sql

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to merge two versions of same dataset(from different data sources , gs bucket and kafka) with only distinct values in the resulting. Though UNION and DISTINCT is an obvious solution , I was looking for a more economical way of doing it .

Comment: that's the most economical solution you'll get